# os.path.join is showing error

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, os.path

I have been trying to implement the fully_connected_feed.py . But the function os.path.join() is showing a syntax error.

```
parser.add_argument(
  '--input_data_dir',
  type=str,

  default=os.path.join(os.getenv('TEST_TMPDIR', '/tmp'),'tensorflow/mnist/input_data'),
  help='Directory to put the input data.'
)
```

The error is -

```
File "fully_connected_feed.py", line 244
default=os.path.join(os.getenv('TEST_TMPDIR', '/tmp'),'tensorflow/mnist/input_data'),
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What can be the problem?

Comment: Python doesn't understand what you wrote. It's not join's fault, in fact the error happens before that point. Probably there is some mistake in your code before the line you posted, which is only detected a bit after where it is.

Comment: @spectras  I have not changed anything in the code. Directly copied and pasted from github - https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/fully_connected_feed.py  . How will I find the issue?

Comment: Are you perhaps running Python 2 code using a Python 3 interpreter?

Comment: @spectras   No that cannot be an issue. The other codes are running fine.

Comment: Is the blank line in your example code here not actually blank in your real code? If so, it's probably the source of the syntax error, though it's only on the `default=...` line that makes Python's parser notice that things have gone wrong. Check for unbalanced parentheses, or a missing trailing comma.